# Why does string String s evaluate to null when I set onClickListener on a button?

Tags: android

I'm facing a problems with an android code. I'm trying to show that string which I received from another fragment by using setOnClickListener but why it shows null string in onClick function?

```
  Bundle b = this.getArguments();
  s = b.getString("key");
```

After I receive this string from another fragment it shows me the null string in button click listener

Comment: Maybe the fragment's arguments does not contains key "key". Could you show putting extra data code?

Comment: Could you show us the code creating this fragment?

Answer (score 0):

Try this or verify your code: assume you are sending from **"sender fragment"**

```
ReceiverFragment rf= new ReceiverFragment ();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("keytosend", "data");
rf.setArguments(args);
```

Now you have set the argument for the new fragment
try to receive in receiver fragment

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, rf).commit();
```

render the new fragment

in the **onCreateView()** method of your ReceiverFragment

Read the value as your are doing earlier

```
String value = getArguments().getString("keytosend");
```